# Rails "order_by" an associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, sql-order-by

I have two database tables, one called "Recipes" and another "Likes".

When I list my recipes on my website I can easily order them by one of the columns within the recipe table. For example by the date they are created at:

```
<% @recipes.order("created_at desc").limit(16).each do |i| %>
  <% if i.live? %>
    <%=link_to image_tag(i.image(:fixed), :class => "newest-recipes"), i %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What I really want to do is to order them by the number of likes they have. To display the number of likes on the recipes page I use this piece code:

```
<%= @recipe.likers.count %>
```

Is there a way of ordering the recipes by @recipe.likers.count?

Please let me know if you require additional information such as the recipe controller or model.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache

Basically, add a new integer column to the `recipes` table called `likes_count`, then edit the `Like` model to look like:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe, counter_cache: true
end
```

Then Rails will automatically update it when necessary and you can just order by that column:

```
@recipes.order(:likes_count)
```

Comment: After you've added it, remember to save all recipes with `Recipe.all.each(:save)` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the @Ju Liu answer (+1). However, in case you cannot add the new column to the existing table, you can create a scope in your `Recipe` model:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes
  scope :likes_count,
    select("recipes.id, ANY_OTHER_COLUMN_YOU_NEED_HERE, count(likes.id) AS likes_count").
    joins(:likes).
    group("recipes.id").
    order("likes_count DESC")
end

@recipes = Recipe.likes_count
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ill have a look into both options